# Date.toLocaleString inadequacy for conversion of a date/time to universal time

Tags: javascript, datetime, datetime-conversion

I'm trying to convert a date object to `UTC`.  Either I'm using it wrong or the `Date.toLocaleString` seems to be broken or inadequate.

```
new Date('Tue Aug 09 2022 18:43:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)')
    .toLocaleString('en-US', {
      timeZone: "UTC",
      day: "2-digit",
      hour12: false,
      year: "numeric",
      month: "2-digit",
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      second: '2-digit',
    })
```

output:

`"08/09/2022, 23:43:00"`  (A valid date/time)

```
new Date('Tue Aug 09 2022 19:43:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)')
    .toLocaleString('en-US', {
      timeZone: "UTC",
      day: "2-digit",
      hour12: false,
      year: "numeric",
      month: "2-digit",
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      second: '2-digit',
    })
```

output:

`"08/10/2022, 24:43:00"`

I expected it to be `"08/10/2022, 00:43:00"` but instead it appears to not reset the hours.

I have worked around this, in the particular way I was using the result, but I would like to be able to go without the extra conditional and reset.

```
    var parts = str.match(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}),\s(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})/),
      month = parseInt(parts[1], 10),
      day = parseInt(parts[2], 10),
      year = parseInt(parts[3], 10),
      hours = parseInt(parts[4], 10),
      minutes = parseInt(parts[5], 10),
      seconds = parseInt(parts[6], 10);

    if (hours == 24) {
      hours = 0;
    }
```

Why is this happening, and how can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hourCycle: "h23"` instead of `hour12: false` in your options. [Read more about the options on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#hourcycle).

```js
console.log(
  new Date('Tue Aug 09 2022 19:43:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)')
  .toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: "UTC",
    day: "2-digit",
    hourCycle: "h23",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "2-digit",
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Very good.  Marking this as the accepted answer.  I'm using an outdated version of typescript and due to this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34399 and because I'm unable to upgrade this project's typescript I can't use the hourCycle property.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's the americain way of displaying time after midnight when using 24-hour (non 12 hour) time. Try using `en-UK` for locale:

```js
console.log(
  new Date('Tue Aug 09 2022 19:43:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)')
  .toLocaleString('en-UK', {
    timeZone: "UTC",
    day: "2-digit",
    hour12: false,
    year: "numeric",
    month: "2-digit",
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
  })
);
```

Comment: Thanks,  this would work, I would have to reinterpret the output accordingly, but I would rather just reset the hours myself.  12 of one, one half dozen of the other, I suppose.  So weird,  I've never encountered that kind of nonsensical time before, to think it's "US specific" is a joke, maybe something highly specific to something associated with the US, but certainly not commonplace!

Comment: It *is* weird. The only thing I found on that strange notation was [here](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/time-24-hour-clock/) (bottom of the page)

Comment: https://www.militarytime.us/midnight-military-time/ explains it well.  It can be a kind of connotation denoting end of day or start of day,  It would be interesting to see a practical use of 'en-US',hour12: false